# Django CMS how do I add a CSS file to the admin

Tags: python, django, django-cms

When using Django CMS, how do you add your own custom CSS file to be loaded in the admin? I'd like to customize the layout of the page admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to copy at least base.html from `/contrib/admin/templates/admin/` to

```
project
--templates
----admin
------base.html
```

There you can tell admin to load whatever .css files you want.